# The max function of tuples in Python

Tags: python

I have a query I am learning python

```
tp = ("monkey" , "mouse")
max(tp)
```

output = mouse

how it is mouse ? why not monkey

I was expecting monkeys will be the answer

I didnt understand any video reference so I am asking here

Comment: Why do you expect *monkey* - what's your understanding about ```max``` and *tuple* supposed to work?

Comment: Strings are compared alphabetically, not by their length.

Comment: Because of how `max` works, `max(tp)` and `max(*tp)` would behave the same. Your question isn't about tuples, but about string comparison.

Answer (score 4):

Strings can be compared for ordering and are compared in *dictionary order*. So `"monkey" < "mouse"` asks the question "should 'monkey' appear before 'mouse' in the dictionary"? And the answer is yes, because the first two letters are the same and the third letter of "monkey" comes earlier in the alphabet than the third of "mouse".

So when you ask for the "bigger" of the two words using `max`, you're asking which word should appear *later* in the dictionary, and that's "mouse".

Comment: Thanks a lot I didnt new that I thought it is based on length

Comment: Prob. OP - you're expecting max(tp, key=len) in the case.

Answer (score 1):

As it seams you are looking for the longest word you can pass a function to `max` with the keyword *key*, from which the order will be used instead.
In this case `key=len` will compare `len("monkey") > len("mouse")`

```py
>>> tp = ("monkey" , "mouse")
>>> max(tp, key=len)
'monkey'
```